# Find the inverse laplace transform (step-function)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Find the inverse laplace transform for

$$F(s) = \frac{e^{-2s}}{s^2+s-2}$$

I have narrowed it down to that it has something to do with step-functions but I can't see it, can I do something with the denominator here?

Comment: **1.** In general terms, if $f(t)$ has Laplace transform $F(s)$, what is the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)e^{-2s}$? $$ $$

**2.** What is the inverse Laplace transform of $$F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 +s - 2}$$

Comment: If you can't answer my first question, watch this lecture on the topic, with MIT's delightful Arthur Mattuck:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-22-using-laplace-transform-to-solve-odes-with-discontinuous-inputs/

Comment: I have actually watch all of those, he is such a great professor! Can you remember in which video this is in?

Anyway, for 2 we can rewrite:

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{s-1} - \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{s+2}$$

This has the inverse Laplace transform

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{3} e^{t} - \frac{1}{3} e^{-2t}$$

Comment: The particular lecture I have given the link to covers the material for answering question 1 and hence your question overall.